# How do I achieve a hook which will be executed after all features? cuucmber js - v 2.1.0

Tags: cucumber, cucumberjs

I tried doing below

```
this.registerHandler('AfterFeatures', function (event, callback) {
    reporter.generate(options);
    callback();
});
```

however, it gives an error that registerError is not a function. Any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 2 changed how both step definitions are defined and how hooks are registered. It should look something like this now...

```
let {defineSupportCode} = require('cucumber');

defineSupportCode(({registerHandler}) => {
  registerHandler('AfterFeatures', function(event, callback) {
    reporter.generate(options);
    callback();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you are using cucumber 1.0

```
var { AfterAll, BeforeAll } = require('cucumber');

this.BeforeAll(function(Scenario,callback) {
    // DO something
    callback();
}

this.AfterAll(function(Scenario,callback) {
    reporter.generate(options);
    callback();
}
```

Comment: Also, see that where you have defined the register Handler. It should be inside
 var hooks = function () {                                 
    this.registerHandler('AfterFeatures', function (event, callback) {
    reporter.generate(options);
    callback();
});                                                                                                                            };                                                                                                                    export = hooks;